# How to block all incoming connections on D-LINK DIR-501 except from one IP?

Tags: networking, router, security, firewall

I have a remote desktop on my computer. It is connected to internet with a D-LINK DIR-501. My internet provider gave my fixed IP.

So, in my system log i have brute force track of attacks to connect to my remote desktop from multiple multiple IP's with different passwords.

What i would like to do is to block it. I would like only one IP from my home being able to make incoming connection to my office network. How should i set it on D-LINK DIR 501? Any instruction for other router would be also nice, since i can apply it to D-LINK DIR 501.

Answer (score 0):

The way to set this up would be with the firewall. What do you have set for the firewall currently? Enable the SPI and proceed to build a firewall rule to allow your RDP connection. Choose a name, set the action to "allow" set the source IP to the WAN IP of your home internet connection. For the destination set the IP to the IP address of your office computer and the port 3389 by default. (You will need to make sure the IP address of your office computer does not change by either giving it a static IP out of the DHCP range or reserving the DHCP IP address for that computer in the router) You will also need a port forwarding rule then in the port forwarding window.
Give it a name and enter a public port of your choosing. Then input the office computer IP and set to "TCP" and set the private port to 3389 unless you changed the default. Enable your rules and set the connection.
Enter the WAN IP of our office internet connection followed by a colon and the public port you chose. Such as xx.xx.xx.xx:**** into your RDP client on your home computer.
Hopefully this works for you. Some of the consumer grade routers are not as good and handling firewall rules along with port forwarding as others. Test to verify it's working as desired.